# Some answers need to be random in the form. Is there just a way to click a variable with the Target as the variable

Tags: selenium

I'm just curious if I can get IDE to click a target that's a variable. So far I believe that the variable is right,but...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="https://docs.google.com/" />
    <title>yolt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">yolt</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>yolo</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>/a/students.d125.org/forms/d/1if5ewBKPn39pphsm92i5gX2Lv8iEx5cOfmnDhTiHmi4/viewform</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_241280888_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_267410756_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1306947924_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[2]/label</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1960845646_1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[4]/div/div/ul/li/label/span[2]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[5]/div/div/ul/li[3]/label/span</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1065210562_3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_10</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_10</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_9</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[6]/div/div/ul/li[8]/label/span[2]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_8</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[6]/div/div/ul/li[7]/label/span[2]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_990809070_7</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1745483943_1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//form[@id='ss-form']/ol/div[7]/div/div/ul/li/label/span[2]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1030193806_6</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_241280888_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_267410756_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1306947924_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1306947924_2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1960845646_1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=group_1065210562_3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>store</td>
        <td>javascript{Math.floor(Math.random()*11)}</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>store </td>
        <td>&quot;id=group_990809070_&quot;+x</td>
        <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>${y}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Basically, it loads a form, answers some questions. But, I was wondering if I can get randomized answers by appending a random int string to the target string. Then just click on that button

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is rather non-functional, but there are some opportunities to do it.
Look at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-ide

You can define helper functions in user-extensions.js

For example if you have two xpath like //div[1] and //div[2] You will define something like

```
type rndAnswer javascript{Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1}
```

and then use a variable {rndAnswer} for clicking //div/[{answer}]